# Reducucing AIR compile time

Tags: actionscript, air, module, swc

I have an AIR app that is quiet big, and compile time is around 40-50 sec.

Good thing is that app is quiet modular, I could easily break it down to modules, and compile them as swc and then recompile only those modules in which I'm working on, like i could do with normal desktop apps. Is it possible to have the same approach on mobile? Is there any way to do that on IOS? As far as I know It would not be possible to load swc on IOS at runtime.

Any other ideas to bring compile time down?

Answer (score 0):

AIR compiler for iOS compiles everything into a normal swf then compiles that swf again into iOS code, and that's where it takes ages!
But you can do a test build which takes some seconds though it runs slower but enough for testing especially if you're using a high end iOS device.

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice, but it's the swf compilation that takes 40-50 seconds.

Comment: Ah, well other than using the new compiler which is supposed to be faster (based on Adobe) I can't think of something as I never had a problem with that.